# Cross-orgin com laravel e vuejs

Tags: htaccess, vue.js, cors, laravel-5.6

Em meu dilema para publicar minha aplicação estou enfrentando alguns problemas.

Estou fazendo o front separado do back. O frontend é em vuejs e o backend em Laravel (sendo apenas uma API)

No servidor está assim:

```
public_html
      index.html
      static
      api
         app
         database
         config
         ....
         public
            .htaccess
```

Sendo que index.html e static são do vuejs e dentro de api estão todos os arquivos do Laravel. No meu htaccess está assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Quando o meu dominio.com faz a requisição para api.meudominio.com me retorna o erro de cross-origin. Como resolver isso?

- Eu não mexi em nenhum outro arquivo do laravel. Apenas adicionei o htacess no public da API. Não sei se tem alguma configuração extra a fazer.

Comment: Verifica se o header está sendo adicionado. Verifica se a rota está com options liberado. O navegador manda um options antes de mandar a requisição post/put/get/delete

Comment: Como vejo essas coisas? O htaccess está correto? E fica mesmo dentro da pasta public do projeto?

Comment: App/http/routes.php

Comment: O htaccess fica na public mesmo, se está certo eu não sei, mas acho que sim

Comment: Não tenho esse arquivo no diretório que vc informou e em nenhuma outra parte do projeto =(

Comment: Tenta App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider  /
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing